# Configuring GIT to Jenkins Slave instead of Jenkins Master

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins Master and three slaves. My builds are saved in a GIT repo. Now, if Jenkins Master take the build from GIT and then transfer that to Slave which will further deploy it on my embedded device, a huge latency comes into the picture as each binary is over 800Mb.

Is there a way i can configure Jenkins Master in a way where Slave directly checkout the build from GIT as instructed by Master and deploy it?

Comment: Are you using pipeline? Then you can use the `checkout` step on a node like this: `node('nodename'){ checkout scm }`.